# Highlight a row on Click not working. CSS precedence

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Here's the `table` in my html file. I have to highlight a row on click.

```
<tbody>
  <!--display none-->
  <!--onclick-->
  <tr ng-repeat="case in lastten" ng-click="setSelected(case.Name)" ng-class="{selected: case.Name === idSelected}">
    <td colspan="1">{{case.Name}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.total}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.passed}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.failed}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

css- initialTable is the class for the above table

```
table.InitialTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.InitialTable td,
th {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.InitialTable th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table.InitialTable td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table.InitialTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f3f7fb;
}

table.InitialTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.InitialTable tr:hover td {
  background: #eee;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

Here's the angular code-

```
 $scope.idSelected = null;
 $scope.setSelected = function(idSelected) {
   $scope.idSelected = idSelected;
 };
```

So basically whenever a row is selected it gets the class selected and it should be highlighted. But the css is not working. So is the precedence of .selected below the hover ?   I also tried a lot of other combinations , but it didn't work. Even important isn't working . I've been stuck at this for quite a while now .

Comment: In such times that you're asking for debugging a problem, first thing would be to provide a snippet here or a jsfiddle atleast

Comment: ok, i'll try create a working plunkr.

Comment: `.InitialTable tr.selected` most likely.

Comment: it's working when i put !important . So there's some precence problem i guess.